# How to use pd.DataFrame method to manually create a dataframe from info scraped using beautifulsoup4

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I made it to the point where all `tr` data data has been scraped and I am able to get a nice printout. But when I go to implement the `pd.DataFrame` as in `df= pd.DataFrame({"A": a})` etc, I get a syntax error

Here is a list of my imported libraries in the Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import bs4 as bs
import requests
import urllib.request
import csv
import html5lib
from pandas.io.html import read_html
import re
```

Here is my code:

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.zipcodestogo.com/Texas/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')

table_rows = soup.find_all('tr')
table_rows

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)

texas_info = pd.DataFrame({
        "title": Texas 
        "Zip Code" : [Zip Code], 
        "City" :[City],
})

texas_info.head()
```

I expect to get a dataframe with two columns, one being the 'Zip Code' and the other the 'Cities'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create manually, with bs4 4.7.1 you can use `:not`, `:contains` and `:nth-of-type` pseudo classes to isolate the two columns of interest, then construct a dict then convert to df

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.zipcodestogo.com/Texas/').read()
soup = bs(source,'lxml')
zips = [item.text for item in soup.select('.inner_table:contains(Texas) td:nth-of-type(1):not([colspan])')]
cities =  [item.text for item in soup.select('.inner_table:contains(Texas) td:nth-of-type(2):not([colspan])')]
d = {'Zips': zips,'Cities': cities}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df[1:].reset_index(drop = True)
```

You could combine selectors into one line:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.zipcodestogo.com/Texas/').read()
soup = bs(source,'lxml')
items = [item.text for item in soup.select('.inner_table:contains(Texas) td:nth-of-type(1):not([colspan]), .inner_table:contains(Texas) td:nth-of-type(2):not([colspan])')]
d = {'Zips': items[0::2],'Cities': items[1::2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df[1:].reset_index(drop = True)
print(df)
```

---

I note you want to create manually but worth knowing for future readers that you could just use pandas read_html

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_html('https://www.zipcodestogo.com/Texas/')[1]
table.columns = table.iloc[1]
table = table[2:]
table = table.drop(['Zip Code Map', 'County'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print(table)
```

Comment: How did you decide what index values to use in the read_html method? Was that based on information from 'inspect element'" I ask because I am trying to duplicate the process on a different website this time but I'm not getting similar results. https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/us-zip-code-latitude-and-longitude/table/?refine.state=TX

Comment: read_html brings back all tables that it can grab so I inspected those until I found the right index. There are other ways like just checking for a wanted header in a loop for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the DataFrame and perform the `for` loop to append each row in the table into the DataFrame.

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [i.text for i in td]
        print(row)
        zipCode = row[0] # assuming first column
        city = row[1] # assuming second column

        df = df.append({"Zip Code": zipCode, "City" : city}, ignore_index=True)
```

If you only need these two columns, you should not include `title` in the DataFrame (that will create another column); that line also happened to be where the syntax error occurred because of the missing comma.

Comment: Append is very slow operation, it will reallocate space each time. It's better to create dict, fill it, and then create dataframe from dict